# Trigger ngModelController $parsers pipeline from a $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I'm writing a directive that requires ngModel and adds formatters and parsers to manipulate the value. It works great, but since the manipulation depends on external data I have to $watch, I'm looking for a way to update the model value from this watch. I tried to call `$setViewValue` but nothing happens (because $viewValue did not change??).

In the following simple example, changes to `factor´ don't update the model value:

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('multiply', multiplyDirective);

function multiplyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            factor: '=multiply'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return value / scope.factor;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return value * scope.factor;
            });

            scope.$watch('factor', function () {
               // how to run the parsers pipeline to update modelvalue?
               ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app ng-init="factor = 1; value = 1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="value" multiply="factor" /> x
  <input type="number" ng-model="factor" />
  = {{ value }}
</body>
```

Edit: It works if I call the internal `$$parseAndValidate` method, but I wonder if there is a public API to enforce the update.

Edit: I figured out, that the behaviour of `ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);` changed in `1.3.0`. Using `1.2.x` the code works!

Answer (score 1):

A tad late, but I have described how you can do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309114/set-model-value-programmatically-in-angular-js/44071623#44071623). This works on AngularJS 1.6.x

Basically you can trigger the `$parsers pipeline` by using `$setViewValue()`.

Below is a code snippet that allows you to programmatically set the ngModel to anything you like, by "hijacking" the $parsers pipeline. This is done using a closure.

Set up a $parser with a closure like this:

```
const hijack = {trigger: false; model: null};
modelCtrl.$parsers.push( val => {
   if (hijack.trigger){
        hijack.trigger = false;
        return hijack.model;
   }
   else { 
      // .. do something else ...
   })
```

Then for (re)setting the model you need to trigger the pipeline by changing the `$viewValue` with `modelCtrl.$setViewValue('newViewValue')`. (Yes it is true that the new view value must be different with respect to the current value).

```
const $setModelValue = function(model){
    // trigger the hijack and pass along your new model
    hijack.trigger = true;
    hijack.model = model; 
    // assuming you have some logic in getViewValue to output a viewValue string
    modelCtrl.$setViewValue( "some new view value" ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is not loaded at all. You need to give the module name to ng-app like `<body ng-app="app">`. And after that just call `ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue)` whenever factor is modified.

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('multiply', multiplyDirective);

function multiplyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            factor: '=multiply'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return value / scope.factor;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                return value * scope.factor
            });

            scope.$watch('factor', function () {
               // how to run the parsers pipeline to update modelvalue?
              ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$viewValue);
             
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-init="factor = 1; value = 1">
  <input type="number" ng-model="value" multiply="factor" /> x
  <input type="number" ng-model="factor" />
  = {{ value }}
</body>
```

Comment: I think 'app' is the default ngApp argument, so the directive did load. But i noticed, that the behaviour changed in 1.3.0. The code with $setViewValue actually works in 1.2.23 but not in 1.3.0!

Comment: Your original post is using angular 1.2.23 with which 'app' is not the default ngApp. My answer is just based on v1.2.23, so can I earn an 'answer accepted' or up vote?

Secondly, for 1.3.x, 'app' is the default ngApp. And apparently $setViewValue is changed somewhat. I might not have an idea on this, but why not just create another scope variable to store the calculated result? Unless you just want to play with `ngModelController` :>

Comment: Yea, i'm sorry for that. I didn't expect this to be an version issue. Just kept the version SO inserted to the snippet. But I can't accept this answer, because it doesn't solve my actual problem I have with 1.3.x.

Comment: ok understood. But I would rather prefer to have another scope variable than `value` to keep the calculated result. Quite straight forward as not to mess up with ngModelController.

Answer (score 0):

From Sources of v1.3.18, I see no public api. The pipeline goes from **$$parseAndValidate** method, which is also called from **$commitViewValue** (need to commit/set different value or it will [return](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js) )