# Set model value programmatically in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I'm an author of [angular-input-modified](https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified) directive.

This directive is used to track model's value and allows to check whether the value was modified and also provides `reset()` function to change value back to the initial state.

Right now, model's initial value is stored in the `ngModelController.masterValue` property and `ngModelController.reset()` function is provided. Please see [the implementation](https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified/blob/master/src/directive/ngModel.js#L151-L160).

I'm using the following statement: `eval('$scope.' + modelPath + ' = modelCtrl.masterValue;');` in order to revert value back to it's initial state. `modelPath` here is actually a value of `ng-model` attribute. This was developed a way back and I don't like this approach, cause `ng-model` value can be a complex one and also nested scopes will break this functionality.

What is the best way to refactor this statement? How do I update model's value directly through the ngModel controller's interface?

Comment: The directive is definitely the wrong place to reset the model. You can reset the view (value) using `ngModelController.$setViewValue`, if you want to. That would in turn also reset the model value.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found so far is to use the [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service in order to parse the Angular's expression in the `ng-model` attribute and retrieve the setter function for it. Then we can change the model's value by calling this setter function with a new value.

## Example:

```
function reset () {
  var modelValueSetter = $parse(attrs.ngModel).assign;
  modelValueSetter($scope, 'Some new value');
}
```

This works much more reliably than `eval()`.

---

If you have a better idea please provide another answer or just comment this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**[previous answer]**

I had trouble with this issue today, and I solved it by triggering and sort of hijacking the `$parsers` pipeline using a closure.

```
const hijack = {trigger: false; model: null};
modelCtrl.$parsers.push( val => {
   if (hijack.trigger){
        hijack.trigger = false;
        return hijack.model;
   }
   else { 
      // .. do something else ...
   })
```

Then for resetting the model you need to trigger the pipeline by changing the `$viewValue` with `modelCtrl.$setViewValue('newViewValue')`.

```
const $setModelValue = function(model){
    // trigger the hijack and pass along your new model
    hijack.trigger = true;
    hijack.model = model; 
    // assuming you have some logic in getViewValue to output a viewValue string
    modelCtrl.$setViewValue( getViewValue(model) ); 
    }
```

By using `$setViewValue()`, you will trigger the `$parsers` pipeline. The function I wrote in the first code block will then be executed with `val = getViewValue(model)`, at which point it would try to parse it into something to use for your `$modelValue` according the logic in there. But at this point, the variable in the closure hijacks the parser and uses it to completely overwrite the current $modelValue.

At this point, `val` is not used in the `$parser`, but it will still be the actual value that is displayed in the DOM, so pick a nice one.

Let me know if this approach works for you.

**[edit]**

It seems that ngModel.$commitViewValue should trigger the $parsers pipeline as well, I tried quickly but couldn't get it to work.